# When I concatenate 2 layers in a neural networrk, I want to add constant weights, how can I do it?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, concatenation

I am using the `concatenate` function in Keras. I have 2 Conv layers (x and y), and I concatenate them by using `concatenate[x, y]`. Now I want to add constant weights to the layers, so I use `concatenate[w1*x, w2*y]`. Is this right? And can the weights be more than 1?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please provide more context to `concatenate[w1*x, w2*y]`, mainly if w1/2 are trainable or not, and what you mean by "more than 1" (and how more than one weight should be applied to a input example)